# Difference of TypeScript function declaration in interfaces

Tags: javascript, function, interface, typescript

What is the difference between these two declarations of functions in TypeScript Interfaces?

```
interface IExample {
  myFunction(str: string): void;
}
```

and

```
interface IExample {
  myFunction: (str: string) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These declarations are completely equivalent.

The only relevant difference here is that the second form can't be used for function overloads:

```
// OK
interface Example {
    myFunction(s: string): void;
    myFunction(s: number): void;
}

// Not OK
interface Example {
    myFunction: (s: string) => void;
    myFunction: (s: number) => void;
}
```