# Difference between named function syntax in Typescript interface declaration

Tags: typescript

It seems there are two ways to declare a named function in an interface in Typescript:

```
export interface Zoo {
  foo(): string
  readonly bar: () => string,
}
```

Two questions:

1. What is the difference between the foo and the bar functions?
2. Why can only bar have the readonly modifier?

UPDATE:

Here is a longer example:

```
export interface Zoo {
  foo(): string
  readonly bar: () => string,
}

export const x: Zoo = {
  foo: () => "a",
  bar: () => "a",
};

x.foo = () => "b"; // No error
x.bar = () => "b"; // Error: Cannot assign to "bar"
```

To me it seems that both ways of declaring are equivalent except for that the second way can be made readonly.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509973/difference-of-typescript-function-declaration-in-interfaces) older answer saying they are equivalent except for the possibility to overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are valid and generate the same Javascript code:

```
exports.x = {
    foo: function () { return "a"; },
    bar: function () { return "a"; }
};
```

But indeed you can assign the `readonly` modifier only to the property.

And the old answer is still valid, the first one can be use for overloaded, the second one no:

```
a.ts(2,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'myFunction'.
a.ts(3,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'myFunction'.
a.ts(3,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'myFunction' must be of type '(s: string) => void', but here has type '(s: number) => void'.
```

To summarize:

1. What is the difference between the foo and the bar functions?

After the code has been (trans)compiled, none. Before, typescript uses `bar`as a property, and `fpo` as a function.

2. Why can only bar have the readonly modifier?

Because function cannot have readonly modifier